# Enforce monotonicity in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I have a list containing pairs of complex numbers.
For example:

```
list = {{10 + I, 3 - 10 I}, {11 - 2 I, 2 - 10 I}, {7 - I, 1 - 9 I}, 
        {3 - 2 I, 1 - 9.1 I}, {1 - I, 1 - 9.3 I}}
```

If I look at the absolute value of the 2nd elements of these pairs, I want that they decrease monotonically with increasing list position.
In the example list, they don't, since

```
Abs[list[[4, 2]]] > Abs[list[[3, 2]]]
```

I would like to enforce monotonicity (which is always decreasing in my case) by setting all the elements which break the monotonicity to zero. It would be enough that all elements after the first one which breaks the monotonicity be set to zero.

In this example the output should be:

```
list = {{10 + I, 3 - 10 I}, {11 - 2 I, 2 - 10 I}, {7 - I, 1 - 9 I}, {3 - 2 I,0}, {1 - I, 0}}
```

The first element of the pairs should be unaffected.

Can anyone help? I tried a couple of things but I failed :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When in doubt, go the direct route

```
list = {{10 + I, 3 - 10 I}, {11 - 2 I, 2 - 10 I}, {7 - I, 
    1 - 9 I}, {3 - 2 I, 1 - 9.1 I}, {1 - I, 1 - 9.3 I}};
val = Abs@list[[1, 2]];
Do[
  If[Abs@list[[n, 2]] <= Abs@val, val = list[[n, 2]], 
   list[[n, 2]] = 0], {n, Length@list}];
list
(* {{10 + I, 3 - 10 I}, {11 - 2 I, 2 - 10 I}, {7 - I, 
  1 - 9 I}, {3 - 2 I, 0}, {1 - I, 0}} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
f1 = With[{l = Length@First@Split[Abs@#[[All, 2]], Not[ #1 <= #2] &]}, 
          MapAt[0 &, #, {{l + 1 ;;, 2}}]] &;

list = {{10 + I, 3 - 10 I}, {11 - 2 I, 2 - 10 I}, {7 - I, 1 - 9 I}, 
        {3 - 2 I, 1 - 9.1 I}, {1 - I, 1 - 9.3 I}};

f1@list
```

> {{10 + I, 3 - 10 I}, {11 - 2 I, 2 - 10 I}, {7 - I, 1 - 9 I}, {3 - 2 I,
>          0}, {1 - I, 0}}

```
f2 = Replace[#, {x___, {a_, b_}, {c_, d_}, y___} /; 
      Abs[b] < Abs[d] :> {x, {a, b}, {c,  0}, ## & @@ ({#[[1]], 0} & /@ {y})}] &;

f3 = Module[{x = #}, x[[2 + LengthWhile[Differences[Abs@x[[All, 2]]], Negative];;, 2]] = 
     0; x] &

f1 @ list == f2 @ list == f3 @ list
```

> True

Answer (score 2):

A slightly different way using [`Split`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Split.html)

```
Join @@ 
 MapAt[# /. {a_, b_} :> {a, 0} &, 
  Split[list, Abs[#1[[2]]] > Abs[#2[[2]]] &], 2 ;;]
(* {{10 + I, 3 - 10 I}, {11 - 2 I, 2 - 10 I}, {7 - I, 
  1 - 9 I}, {3 - 2 I, 0}, {1 - I, 0}} *)
```